# Is there a way to create an enum that can't be null?

Tags: java, enums

I've been finding several bugs in my project that are due to enums being null, instead of one of the enumerated values. Is there a way to guarantee that a variable of this type will always be initialized with one of the enumerated values, and never be null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Enums are always reference types, and `null` is a valid value for any reference type. You can *always* write:

```
MyEnum x = null;
```

and if you have an instance or static variable which isn't initialized explicitly, it will always default to null.

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be done (very, very painfully) by picking a Java [Design By Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract#Languages_with_third-party_support) system and changing every function that takes in an enum to require it not to be null.  This is, of course, a gigantic amount of work to do on an existing project.

On a more practical note, you might consider integrating a [static code analysis tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java) into your build process.  This is also a big amount of work (it will potentially find a giant set of "bugs"), but is probably doable (still painfully) if you have the time to invest in it.  The right static code analysis tool can possibly detect this kind of error.